# How to retrieve a key from a particular position in JSON (Google App Script)

Tags: javascript, json, key

How can I retrieve key11-key44?

> P.S. I was able to retrieve values key1-key4:
>
> var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
>
> var keys = Object.keys(data.paths);
>
> for (var a in keys) {return keys[a]}

---

```
{
        "id": "123",
        "name": "abc",
        "paths": {
                "key1": {
                        "key11": "value"
                },
                "key2": {
                        "key22": "value"
                },
                "key3": {
                        "key33": "value"
                },
                "key4": {
                        "key44": "value"
                }
        }
}
```

---

Comment: data.paths.key1.key11
data.paths.key4.key44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because  keys[a] can be key1, key2, ... key4 you can use again Object.keys in order to get the child key:

```js
var data = {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "abc",
    "paths": {
        "key1": {
            "key11": "value"
        },
        "key2": {
            "key22": "value"
        },
        "key3": {
            "key33": "value"
        },
        "key4": {
            "key44": "value"
        }
    }
};

var keys = Object.keys(data.paths);

for (var a in keys) {
    console.log(Object.keys(data.paths[keys[a]])[0])
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I needed! Object.keys(data.paths[keys[a]])[0]